# Why is my function appending the file name string instead of the lines of the file itself?

Tags: python, function, file

I am trying to append the lines of a file (.py file) to a list as a way to count the lines and figure out which lines are code using a conditional statement. The problem is that my function that I created is reading the 'file name' instead of the lines of the file itself. Where did I go wrong with this. I am surprised I got this far...it works, but not for the right reason.

```
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
import time

def getFileName():
    sourceCode = askopenfilename() # Opens dialog box to locate and select file
    return sourceCode

def scLines():
    scList = []
    sourceCode = getFileName()
    for line in sourceCode:
        if line[0] != "#" or line != "":
           scList.append(line)
    return scList

def countscLine():
    lineCount = len(scLines())
    return lineCount

def fCount():
    fList = []
    sourceCode = getFileName()
    for line in sourceCode:
        if line[0:3] == 'def ':
            fAmout.append(line)
    lineCount = len(fList)
    return fList

# Get file name from user
def main():
    print("Select the file to be analyzed")
    time.sleep(5) # Waits 5 seconds before initiating function
    sourceCode = getFileName()
    print("The file is", sourceCode)
    print("The source code has ", countscLine(), "lines of code, and", fCount(), "functions.")
    print(scLines())
    print("")

main()
```

Comment: In `scLines` you never open the file. You just iterate over the characters in the filename.

Comment: BTW, why don't you save your file selection and use the file name as a parameter for the appropriate functions? Your program will ask for a filename three times and each time someone might enter a different name.

Comment: Okay...thanks. I thought that is what I had done, but looking more closely, each time I call the function, it will execute...programming requires a lot of attention to detail. Thanks for bringing that to my attention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is `for line in sourceCode:`.  You need to actually open the file.

```py
with open(sourceCode) as f:
    for line in f:
        if line[0] != "#" or line != "":
            scList.append(line)
```

I'd recommend renaming some of your variables to be more clear as to what they actually do.  For example, I would call `sourceCode` `sourceCodefn` or similar to indicate that it is a file name.

Comment: :) You're awesome!!! I figured it was something simple. Duly noted for variables. Thanks a million! The 'with' function is something I haven't learned yet in my class, so I will have to play around with that.

Comment: The `with` statement (not function!) just opens the file and automatically does the cleanup for you. But, conceptually, you could just replace your `for line in SourceCodeFilename` with `for line in open(SourceCodeFilename)` [note changed variable name], although this might not actually close the file until the end of the program.

Comment: @RashadJackson would you mind marking this solution as accepted, if this is what you went with?  Thanks.